# How To show RemoteIPAddress in acumatica UI Form also DAC Property we will used?

Tags: acumatica

How To show Remote IP Address in acumatica UI(ASPX Form) also DAC Property we will used?

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds two unbound fields to SOOrder, you can add these fields to the SO Order Entry screen.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace PX.Objects
{
  // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
  public class SOOrderIPExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
  {
    #region UsrExternalIP
    [PXString(30)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="External IP")]
    [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(ExternalIPConstant), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string UsrExternalIP { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrExternalIP : Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrExternalIP> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrClientIP
    [PXString(30)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Client IP")]
    [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(ClientIPConstant), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string UsrClientIP { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrClientIP : Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrClientIP> { }
    #endregion

    public class ExternalIPConstant : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<ExternalIPConstant>
    {
        public ExternalIPConstant() : base(getExternalIP()) { }
    }

    public class ClientIPConstant : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<ExternalIPConstant>
    {
        public ClientIPConstant() : base(getClientIP()) { }
    }

    public static string getExternalIP()
    {
        try
        {
            var externalIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
            return externalIP;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string getClientIP()
    {
        string clientIP;
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null || request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] != null)
            clientIP = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        else
            clientIP = request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        return clientIP;
    }
  }
}
```